# Many font files in my application causing .xib files not to load

Tags: iphone, ios

I have 600 font files in my iphone application, the application fails to find the .xib files with those 600 files included in it. If I remove the 600 files, the .xib file is loaded correctly without a problem.

I checked limitation on number of resource files in the application and there is none. Also, the size of the files are only 100MB which is OK. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Wait, did you just say **SIX HUNDRED** font files? What in god's name would you be doing with 600 font files? Are there even that many fonts out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have good news and bad news. The badnews is that you are probably hitting some soft limit in iOS, since Apple never envisioned someone wanting that many fonts in an iPhone.

The good news (sort of) is that you can load CGFonts and CTFonts directly from files [see link](http://www.freetimestudios.com/2010/09/13/custom-fonts-on-the-ipad-and-ios-4/#load-the-font-into-memory). The bad part of this is that you'll have to do your drawing with Core Graphics or Core Text, since these things are not toll free bridged.

Answer (score 0):

thank you. This worked. However, it requires creating new layers to write in instead of the old ones..

here's the complete code snippet

```
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


CTFontRef ctfont =  [self newCustomFontWithName:@"cs" ofType:@"ttf" attributes:nil];
CATextLayer *  normalTextLayer_ = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];

normalTextLayer_.font = ctfont;
normalTextLayer_.string = @"alleluja";
normalTextLayer_.wrapped = YES;
normalTextLayer_.foregroundColor = [[UIColor purpleColor] CGColor];
normalTextLayer_.fontSize = 20.f;
normalTextLayer_.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
normalTextLayer_.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 10.f, 320.f, 32.f);

[self.view.layer addSublayer:normalTextLayer_];    


CTFontRef cttFont =  [self newCustomFontWithName:@"cs" ofType:@"ttf" attributes:nil];
NSString *fontName = [(NSString *)CTFontCopyName(cttFont, kCTFontPostScriptNameKey) autorelease];

CGFloat fontSize = CTFontGetSize(cttFont);
NSLog(@"%f fontName = '%@'",fontSize,fontName);
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];
UITextView * xx = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 200)];
xx.text = @"alleluja";
xx.font = font;



[self.view addSubview:xx];
```